# How to find two files having the same content in apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have one scenario that is to find the contents of the two files are same or not
let say i have a file one.txt and it has the below data
3000|AAA
3001|BBB
3002|CCC

And the other file two.txt
3000|AAA
3001|BBB
3002|CCC
30003|DDD
now i want to compare these two files and say whether both are same or not